# "Value does not fall within the expected range" exception in ListView

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

For Windows 8 application development environment.

Code:

```
   var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
   listView.ItemsSource = deserialized; // error
```

Data model:

```
    public class C
    {
        public List<Y> programs { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int code { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<C> cs { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
    }
    public class Y
    {
        public string category { get; set; }
        public string time { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

What can I do ? I don't find solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ItemsSource` is looking for an `IEnumerable`, but you're providing a single object in `RootObject`. You'd get the same error if you create one of your RootObject instances in code and try the same assignment.

What specifically should be displaying in the list?  If you simply change your code to:

```
listView.ItemsSource = deserialized.cs;
```

the listView should display your `C` objects.

Comment: I asked but thought about and found it! :) Nevertheless thanks.Your answer true.

Answer (score 0):

I always have trouble figuring out how to go from the serializer output.  I do have working code (windows 8 store) that I'm pasting below.  It is pretty obvious what it does.

```
                HttpResponseMessage responseGetEmailByPersonsBare =
                         await clientGetEmailByPersonsBare.PostAsync(UrlBase + EmailDetailGetEmailByPersonsBare, contentGetEmailByPersonsBare);
                     Stream myStream = await responseGetEmailByPersonsBare.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                     var djsGetEmailByPersonsBare = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(AEWebDataStructures.RootObjectEmailDetail));

                     var rootObjectEmailDetail = (AEWebDataStructures.RootObjectEmailDetail)djsGetEmailByPersonsBare.ReadObject(myStream);
                     responseGetEmailByPersonsBare.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                     returnTaskInfo.EmailDetails = rootObjectEmailDetail.Data;
                     returnTaskInfo.StatusReturn = AEWebDataStructures.StatusReturn.Success;
```